# If, Else if, Else not working Only if and Else Working

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have the following query:

```
Declare @qty int
SET @qty = (SELECT Qty FROM StockTB WHERE ProductID='6' AND Qty=0)
if(@qty =0)
Update StockTB SET Qty=Qty+5, BatchNo='1234', ExpDate='03/11/2018' WHERE 
ProductID='6' AND Qty=0
Else
INSERT INTO StockTB Values('6', '5', '1234', '03/11/2018')
```

The above query is working fine. But when I add `ELSE IF`  in the query, it fails. Here is after having `ELSE IF` implementation.

```
Declare @expdate date
SET @expdate =(SELECT ExpDate FROM StockTB WHERE ProductID='6' AND 
ExpDate='03/11/2018')
Declare @qty int
SET @qty = (SELECT Qty FROM StockTB WHERE ProductID='6' AND Qty=0)
if(@qty =0)
Update StockTB SET Qty=Qty+5, BatchNo='1234', ExpDate='03/11/2018' WHERE 
ProductID='6' AND Qty=0
Else if(@expdate='03/11/2018')
Update StockTB SET Qty=Qty+5 WHERE ProductID='6' AND ExpDate='03/11/2018'
Else
INSERT INTO StockTB Values('6', '5', '1234', '03/11/2018')
```

Comment: `SET @qty = (SELECT Qty FROM StockTB WHERE ProductID='6' AND Qty=0)` - when do you expect that to be non-zero?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever There's one case: if no result (`NULL`) is returned by the query.

Comment: @MatSnow - agreed - this would be a *very bizarre* way of writing what appears to just need to be a single `MERGE`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean " Failed to work"? What do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: There are many things here that are challenging. It all starts with the formatting of your code. You have this written as a wall of text which is very difficult to read. Use white space to make things easier on yourself. You seem to be putting single quotes around numbers, your date format is dependent on the date settings and you really should list the columns in your insert statements.

Comment: You should read about MERGE. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql It is a lot easier way to handle this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2):

I can't read your schema, but it seems that "ExpDate" is a date.
You are comparing it to a `varchar` `'03/11/2018'`

I don't know if you mean November 3 or March 11. Neither SQL do know.
Try to `CONVERT(VARCHAR, ExpDate, 103)` instead:

At:
`Else if(@expdate='03/11/2018')`

Change it to:
`Else if(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @expdate, 103) = '03/11/2018')`

You can also achieve the same result using that on the query to set the `@expdate` value (And make it `VARCHAR`, not date)

*Ps: The magic number `103` as argument means `dd/mm/yyyy`. You can get a full list [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql).

Comment: Or use the ANSI standard YYYYMMDD.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
Declare @expdate date
SET @expdate =(SELECT ExpDate FROM StockTB WHERE ProductID='6' AND 
ExpDate='2018/11/03')
Declare @qty int
SET @qty = (SELECT Qty FROM StockTB WHERE ProductID='6' AND Qty=0)
if(@qty =0)
Update StockTB SET Qty=Qty+5, BatchNo='1234', ExpDate='2018/11/03' WHERE 
ProductID='6' AND Qty=0
Else 
if(@expdate='2018/11/03')
Update StockTB SET Qty=Qty+5 WHERE ProductID='6' AND ExpDate='2018/11/03'
Else
INSERT INTO StockTB Values('6', '5', '1234', '2018/11/03')
```

Comment: This isn't any different than what the OP posted.